# CSS: background-position: ???;

Tags: css, background-position

Hopefully these diagrams explain what I'm after. The red signifying the background and the grey the webpage.

#### Wrong

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

#### Right

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

How do I achive this? I've tried `background-position: bottom right;` but it's just all wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should as your question at [doctype](http://doctype.com/), There you'll find more people with the expertise to answer your question

Comment: Looks like your images are broken. I don't suppose you might have them around to re-upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
body
{ 
background-image:url('smiley.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:bottom right; 
}
```

And if the picture is big enough the no-repeat isn't needed. (Works even in IE6).

Comment: I think `background-attachment:fixed;` is what did it.

Answer (score 2):

```
background-position: right bottom;
```

should do the trick.

Reference: [**CSS background-position Property**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp)

> xpos ypos - The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. The top left corner is 0 0. Units can be pixels (0px 0px) or any other CSS units. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. You can mix % and positions

Answer (score 1):

`background-position: bottom right` should indeed do what you describe.

If you want the image to stick to the bottom-right of the *viewport* rather than the document, you will have to add `background-attachment: fixed`. There are problems with this in IE, but when used on the main body/html background it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot

```
background-position: absolute
```